# Struct data assignment error: closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

Tags: json, swift, struct, computed-properties

I'm trying to get a json thanks to the computed properties of "struct" and it gives error: Closure can not implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

```
struct getData: Encodable, Decodable {
    var dataAPI: ItemsStruct

    init(url: String!) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                // Convert the data to JSON
                let jsonSerialized = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ItemsStruct.self, from: data)

                self.dataAPI = jsonSerialized!   <--error: closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make `dataAPI` an optional.

Comment: You would also have to use a class instead of struct

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain why you have this error.
You have a structure called `getData`. As you may know a `struct` is value type passed and not a referenced type as a `class`.

Meaning that if you change your data model through a function in a structure basically you are changing the structure itself. Here in your `init` in your closure, you are changing `dataAPI` which is part of your data model for your `struct`. That's the meaning of *a mutating self parameter*. The compiler knows that you are changing the structure by mutating `dataAPI` parameter.

If you want to keep as a `struct`, I recommand you to create a `mutating func` where you initialize your `dataAPI` variable.